# Unable to print to CUPS printers with firefox

Tags: firefox, printing, cups

I am using Firefox 50.0.1 on Arch Linux. I am unable to print to any of my CUPS printers. The only printer that shows up in the print dialog is "print to file". I am able to use cups printers from the command line and a variety of other applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Arch the [gtk3-print-backends](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gtk3-print-backends/) package is required for printing for some applications including Firefox. The gtk3-print-backends package is an optional dependency for the [gtk3](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gtk3/) package, but is not listed as an optional dependency for the [firefox](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/firefox/) package making tracing down the problem a little difficult.